Issue with Firebase request - Taking more than 10 minutes randomly
I am writing several documents in my application following the acceptance of a "reservation".
So I'm executing the following function, with a batch.
Sometimes it executes correctly, sometimes it takes more than 10 minutes to execute, on the same device, same network.
Has anyone had a similar problem? How can I solve it? Or where can I find a way to diagnose it?
Thanks in advance !
Future<void> accepterReservation() async {
    print('accepter resa');
    setState(() {
      accepterResaIsLoading = true;
    });

    ChatsRecord docChatMAJ =
        await ChatsRecord.getDocumentOnce(widget.chatDoc!.reference);

    int? prixLoc = docChatMAJ.prix;
    DateTime? dateDebut = docChatMAJ.dateDebut;
    DateTime? dateFin = docChatMAJ.dateFin;
    int daysDifference = dateFin!.difference(dateDebut!).inDays;

    if (docChatMAJ?.offrePrix != null && docChatMAJ?.offrePrix != 0) {
      setState(() {
        _model.prixCommunique = docChatMAJ?.offrePrix;
      });
      print(_model.prixCommunique);
    } else {
      print('ici');
      _model.prixCommunique = docChatMAJ?.prix;
      print(_model.prixCommunique);
    }

    String baseTextP =
        'La réservation sera validée une fois que le locataire aura réglé le montant de la location.';
    String baseTextL =
        'Effectue le paiement de ta location pour valider la réservation.';

    if (daysDifference > 6) {
      baseTextP +=
          '\nLoomi ne prend pas en charge la caution pour les locations de plus de 6 jours, nous t\'invitons à te rapprocher du locataire pour sa mise en place.';
      baseTextL +=
          '\nLoomi ne prend pas en charge la caution pour les locations de plus de 6 jours, nous t\'invitons à te rapprocher du propriétaire pour sa mise en place.';
    }

    WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

    // On crée le message pour le locataire
    DocumentReference newChatMsgLoc = ChatMessagesRecord.collection.doc();
    batch.set(
      newChatMsgLoc,
      createChatMessagesRecordData(
        type: 'notification_reservation',
        destinataire: docChatMAJ.locataire,
        titre:
            'Le propriétaire a accepté ton offre de location du ${dateTimeFormat('dd/MM/y', dateDebut)} au ${dateTimeFormat('dd/MM/y', dateFin)} pour un montant de ${(fromCentimesToEuros(_model.prixCommunique)! / 1.18).toStringAsFixed(2)}€.',
        timestamp: getCurrentTimestamp,
        chat: docChatMAJ.reference,
        text: baseTextL,
      ),
    );

    // On crée le message pour le propriétaire
    DocumentReference newChatMsgProp = ChatMessagesRecord.collection.doc();
    batch.set(
      newChatMsgProp,
      createChatMessagesRecordData(
        destinataire: docChatMAJ.proprietaire,
        titre:
            'Tu as accepté la demande de location du ${dateTimeFormat('dd/MM/y', dateDebut)} au ${dateTimeFormat('dd/MM/y', dateFin)} pour un montant de ${(fromCentimesToEuros(_model.prixCommunique)! / 1.18).toStringAsFixed(2)}€.',
        text: baseTextP,
        type: 'notification_info',
        timestamp: getCurrentTimestamp,
        chat: docChatMAJ.reference,
      ),
    );

    // On mets à jour le chat
    batch.update(
      widget.chatDoc!.reference,
      {
        'lastMessage': 'Offre de location acceptée',
        'lastMessageTime': getCurrentTimestamp,
        'prix': _model.prixCommunique,
        'date_debut': dateDebut,
        'date_fin': dateFin,
        'statutLocation': 'Demande acceptée',
        'last_message_seen_by': FieldValue.arrayUnion([currentUserReference]),
      },
    );

    // Supprimer le message de demande de réservation
    batch.delete(widget.chatMessagesDoc!.reference);

    // Suppression du message permettant au locataire d'annuler sa demande
    if (widget.chatMessagesDoc!.msgAssocie != null) {
      batch.delete(widget.chatMessagesDoc!.msgAssocie!);
    }

    try {
      batch.commit();
      print('fin du batch');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Erreur lors de l\'exécution du batch : $e');
    }

    print('fin du batch2');

    setState(() {
      accepterResaIsLoading = false;
      _model.lastSeenBy = [];
    });
  }

Initially, I had put an await in my code, but then all my firebase requests stopped working in my application, and it became usable.
So I removed the await, but that doesn't solve the problem of my request taking 10 minutes for no reason. I have the same problems in several part of my application, but it's happening randomly, I can't find the root cause of the problem.

I understand that you removed the await keyword for debugging purpose but you need to await batch.commit().

Yes but by doing so my all application is freezing while it await the end of the commit.
Now I've done a batch.commit().then((_) {} ...
So I can use my application while the batch is 'commiting', but it's still taking sometimes like 10 minutes

"it's still taking sometimes like 10 minutes" This is not normal, writes (incl. delete and updates) to the DB shall be much faster (unless you have a very slow connection...). Debug suggestion: Can you try to take each document you add to the batch and try the batch with only this document, to see if you find a pattern with a specific doc...

Yes I know :'(
In fact I have more details about the problem : on some devices, when I commit the batch, I will see on my local device the news documents, I can even see on my debug consol the ID of those documents, but they are not in fact created on my database.
In my chat application for exemple, I have user A & B sending each other messages. I testing my app on two differents devices.
If A send a message to B, B will see it, document will be created
But when B create a message, it's not always created. It will just appears on my local device, but not in my database.
